# Unknown factor in partial derivative

Tags: partial-derivative

On [A Step by Step Backpropagation Example](https://mattmazur.com/2015/03/17/a-step-by-step-backpropagation-example/), in the section **The Backwards Pass** - **Output Layer**, after the graphic, the author wrote:

$\frac{\partial E_{total}}{\partial out_{o1}}=2* \frac{1}{2}(target_{o1}-out_{o1})^{2-1}*-1+0$

Please explain where the factor $-1$ comes from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $-1$ factor comes from the chain rule. When differentiating
$$(x - y)^2$$
partially with respect to $y$, you differentiate the outer square function, leaving the inner function in tact, and then multiply by the derivative of the inner function
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial y} (x - y) = -1.$$